# Synonym Perl6 and Raku

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

TLDR: Raku is an alias name for the language [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), so it should be an alias on SO.

---

Note that [Perl 5](https://perl.org) and [Perl 6](https://perl6.org) are separate languages in the same way as C++ and C#, and that when people talk about Perl they generally mean Perl 5.
That is that 5 and 6 are (now) part of the name; they are **not** version numbers.
(Even though the [perl] and [perl5] tags should be aliases, or the [perl] tag removed; I'm not going to discuss that any further here.)

---

As a way to try to try to improve this misunderstanding, there was a call for an alias to be created for Perl 6.

Recently a [decision](https://colabti.org/irclogger/irclogger_log/perl6?date=2018-10-25#l584) was made by Larry Wall (the creator of Perl). He [decided](https://colabti.org/irclogger/irclogger_log/perl6-dev?date=2018-11-03#l276) on the name of [Raku](https://github.com/perl6/roast/blob/master/docs/announce/6.d.md).

So I am asking that the [perl6] and [raku] tags become synonyms.

Right now [perl6] should be the primary tag.

Note that someone already went and changed a lot of questions that were already tagged with [perl6] to also be tagged with [raku]. Presumably this was done because of a [FaceBook conversation](https://www.facebook.com/groups/perl6/?multi_permalinks=2219303695002644%2C2219202928346054%2C2219146985018315%2C2219121021687578%2C2219060838360263).

---

Transcript of Larry Wall choosing Raku as the alias:

[2018-10-25 #perl6:](https://colabti.org/irclogger/irclogger_log/perl6?date=2018-10-25#l584)

> 18:26 TimToady:   Zoffix: just a heads up wrt the alias, which I'm thinking of as "It's the stage name (but Perl 6 still cashes the checks)"; at the moment I'm liking Raku the best for a short name (it's 4 letters like Enya or Pink or Gaga), with long names of either Raku-go or Go-raku (where "go" is Japanese 語 for "language") because I'm not terribly fond of the "-lang" neologism
>   18:27 TimToady:   Ofun is a close second, but unfortunately "fun" is Japanese for excrement :)
>   18:29 TimToady:   also Raku pottery is "imperfect but sophisticated", so that's a fit :)
>   18:30 TimToady:   most of the existing uses of "raku" in trademarks appears to be for medical supplies or food processing
>   18:31 TimToady:   and there doesn't seem to be an existing "raku" command, at least that Linux Mint knows about

[2018-11-03 #perl6-dev:](https://colabti.org/irclogger/irclogger_log/perl6-dev?date=2018-11-03#l276)

> 18:21     TimToady dips in from vacating with his grandkids to backlog and say: Raku, Final Answer
>   18:21     TimToady doubts he will win a million dollars though...

Note that TimToady is a play on the [TIMTOWTDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it) acronym; which is why Larry chose it for his irc nick.

Comment: See the discussion happen in real-time on [#perl6](https://colabti.org/irclogger/irclogger_log/perl6?date=2018-11-05#l1466).

Comment: This should be resolved in 6 to 8 years...

Comment: Since the language has [officially been renamed](https://raku.org/), and most new questions are now being tagged [tag:raku], can this be implemented, except I guess the other way around? I don't have enough rep to propose a synonym

Comment: @JoKing Actually even if you had enough rep you couldn't do it since the server thinks that [perl6] is a version of [perl].

Comment: Huh weird... Is there any way to proceed from here, or do we just leave it as is?

Comment: There is a newer question reflecting the new situation (Raku is the official name of the language) here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391733/make-perl6-a-synonym-for-raku

Answer (score 17):

Creating a synonym seems like the most sensible move to me. If anyone wants to go ahead and do it, I'll add my vote.

Comment: But [tag:raku], the new name of the language, should be the primary one.

Answer (score 6):

I'm less enthralled with [raku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raku) based on what's said [in the announcement](https://github.com/perl6/roast/blob/master/docs/announce/6.d.md).

> It can be used interchangeably with the original "Perl 6" name or even be combined with it to form "Raku Perl 6". Pick the one that works the best for you and use it consistently.

Perl 6 is *just fine* as long as we use it consistently.

Comment: I'm only posting this because someone has already changed more than 100 [perl6] questions to also have the [raku] tag. I see this continuing regardless of your feelings.

Comment: @BradGilbert:  A moderator can put a stop to that quick-fast and in a hurry, irrespective of *their* feelings.  We as the community simply need to come to a consensus.

Comment: Which is why I didn't wait to post this.

Comment: Note that Perl 6 is not “_just fine_ as long as we use it consistently”, there have been a lot of heated arguments about changing the name that have come up many times in the past 10 or more years. (Mostly Perl 5 people bringing it up.)

Comment: I feel that making the [tag:raku] tag primary for [tag:perl6] is what would work best *for Stack Overflow* because that's one way to try to enforce consistency. If you don't, you end up in the morass of ambiguity that we have for [tag:perl] and [tag:python] and a number of other tags.

Answer (score 3):

Hey I am the guy who created the tag and tagged the questions then stopped as soon as I realized people are getting upset about it. Sorry about that.

Anyway I was wondering, *if* it gets decided to create the synonym, how does creating an alias between tags vs adding a new tag to the questions work with regards to google?

Will people searching for "Raku junctions" on google be able to find perl6 junction questions on stackoverflow that are tagged with only [perl6] if the Raku tag is an alias to perl6?
Or does an alias only affect people using stackoverflow search?

Comment: I may be wrong, but two thirds of your answer kinda look like a question.

Comment: You are not wrong. Also three thirds of the original question kinda do not look like a question either. Is that an issue? 
My questions are meant to highlight one of the not discussed pro/cons of creating an alias vs adding a new tag in order to help reach a decision. Do you think I should rephrase it to sound like an answer? And rephrase the original request to sound like a question? I thought meta was also for meta discussion and support requests not just questions and answers.

Answer (score -5):

FWIW, I'm ok with a 'raku' tag for *new* questions about 'raku'.

IMO 'Raku Perl 6' is an misuse of the "stage name" granted by Larry Wall.  What is happening here is a thinly veiled attempt at a coup d'etat.

So please, please, revert tagging of existing perl6 questions as 'raku'.

Comment: This seems to be missing the point of the request, which is to have all 'raku' tags add a 'perl6' tag instead so this exact situation is avoided.