# Please rename [perl6] to [raku]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The perl6 programming language has been renamed to Raku programming language. reference: https://lwn.net/Articles/802329/

Comment: A synonym would be better; it's been "Perl 6" for several years. (And in my head that's how I'll always think about it.)

Comment: Previously: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376267/synonym-perl6-and-raku