# Make Perl6 a synonym for Raku

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

The Perl 6 programming language was officially renamed to Raku a while ago.

- The language's official web site (https://www.raku.org/) doesn't even mention Perl 6.
- This is what https://www.perl.org/ has to say about it:

  [image: "Raku (formerly known as Perl 6)"]

People have started using the [raku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raku) tag, leaving us two distinct tags for the language: [perl6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl6) and [raku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raku). [perl6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl6) should be made a synonym of [raku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raku).

There was an [request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376267/589924) a year ago to make [raku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raku) a synonym of [perl6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl6) which was never implemented. Since we now have an official, fully-supported name change, [raku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raku) should be the primary tag (being the official name of the language).

Note that [perl6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl6) can't be suggested as a synonym for [raku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raku) using the standard mechanism due to the relative newness of Raku.

[image: "Can't create synonym; the 'perl6' tag appears more than 1.25 times the 'raku' tag]

Comment: You have sufficient reputation and tag score to suggest perl6 as a [tag synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/raku/synonyms) of raku if you like (or vice versa). If a few people agree with you and vote up your suggestion on that page, the synonym will happen automatically.

Comment: @TylerH, I was not aware of that! However, it doesn't work in this case because of the relative newness of Raku (See updated petition.)

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of the frequency safeguard. That could perhaps be rectified by some editing in of [tag:raku] on questions where [tag:perl6] exists but [tag:raku] doesn't.

Comment: @TylerH no synonym can be suggested for perl6, since it's considered a version. It's not really, as exemplified by the fact that it's changed its name.

Comment: @TylerH, Just to be clear, do you mean the system won't let us because the system considers it a version? Does that means that it's absolutely impossible?

Comment: @ikegami SO won't allow a synonym raku -> perl6 because of the version limitation. I think the other way round (perl6 -> raku, what this question is about) is not affected.